# Is there a way to use dplyr distinct() to consider similar values as equal?

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct, disambiguation

I have to do an analysis of scientific papers published in a list of over 20,000 journals. My list has over 450,000 records but with several duplicates (ex: a paper with more than one author from different institutions appear more than once).

Well, I need to count the distinct number of papers per journal, but the problem is that different authors not always provide the information in the same way, and I can get something like the following table:

```
JOURNAL          PAPER
0001-1231        A PRE-TEST FOR FACTORING BIVARIATE POLYNOMIALS WITH COEFFICIENTS
0001-1231        A PRETEST FOR FACTORING BIVARIATE POLYNOMIALS WITH COEFFICIENTS
0001-1231        THE P3 INFECTION TIME IS W[1]-HARD PARAMETERIZED BY THE TREEWIDTH
0001-1231        THE P3 INFECTION TIME IS W-HARD PARAMETERIZED BY THE TREEWIDTH
0001-1231        COMPOSITIONAL AND LOCAL LIVELOCK ANALYSIS FOR CSP
0001-1231        COMPOSITIONAL AND LOCAL LIVELOCK ANALYSIS FOR CSP
0001-1231        AIDING EXPLORATORY TESTING WITH PRUNED GUI MODELS
0001-1231        DECYCLING WITH A MATCHING
0001-1231        DECYCLING WITH A MATCHING
0001-1231        DECYCLING WITH A MATCHING
0001-1231        DECYCLING WITH A MATCHING.
0001-1231        DECYCLING WITH A MATCHING
0001-1231        ON THE HARDNESS OF FINDING THE GEODETIC NUMBER OF A SUBCUBIC GRAPH
0001-1231        ON THE HARDNESS OF FINDING THE GEODETIC NUMBER OF A SUBCUBIC GRAPH.
0001-1232        DECISION TREE CLASSIFICATION WITH BOUNDED NUMBER OF ERRORS
0001-1232        AN INCREMENTAL LINEAR-TIME LEARNING ALGORITHM FOR THE OPTIMUM-PATH
0001-1232        AN INCREMENTAL LINEAR-TIME LEARNING ALGORITHM FOR THE OPTIMUM-PATH 
0001-1232        COOPERATIVE CAPACITATED FACILITY LOCATION GAMES
0001-1232        OPTIMAL SUFFIX SORTING AND LCP ARRAY CONSTRUCTION FOR ALPHABETS
0001-1232        FAST MODULAR REDUCTION AND SQUARING IN GF (2 M )
0001-1232        FAST MODULAR REDUCTION AND SQUARING IN GF (2 M)
0001-1232        ON THE GEODETIC NUMBER OF COMPLEMENTARY PRISMS
0001-1232        DESIGNING MICROTISSUE BIOASSEMBLIES FOR SKELETAL REGENERATION
0001-1232        GOVERNANCE OF BRAZILIAN PUBLIC ENVIRONMENTAL FUNDS: ILLEGAL ALLOCATION
0001-1232        GOVERNANCE OF BRAZILIAN PUBLIC ENVIRONMENTAL FUNDS: ILLEGAL ALLOCATION
0001-1232        GOVERNANCE OF BRAZILIAN PUBLIC ENVIRONMENTAL FUNDS - ILLEGAL ALLOCATION
```

My goal is to use something like:

```
data%>%
distinct(JOURNAL, PAPER)%>%
group_by(JOURNAL)%>%
mutate(papers_in_journal = n())
```

So, I would have information like:

```
JOURNAL      papers_in_journal
0001-1231    6
0001-1232    7
```

The problem is that you can see some errors in the name of the papers published. Some have a "period" at the end; some have spaces or replace symbols; some have other minor variations such as W[1]-HARD versus W-HARD. So, if I run the code as is, what I have is:

```
JOURNAL      papers_in_journal
0001-1231    10
0001-1232    10
```

My question: is there any way to consider a similarity margin either in the use of distinct() or a similar command, so I can have something like distinct(JOURNAL, PAPER %whithin% 0.95)?

In this sense, I want the command to consider:

```
A PRE-TEST FOR FACTORING BIVARIATE POLYNOMIALS WITH COEFFICIENTS
=
A PRETEST FOR FACTORING BIVARIATE POLYNOMIALS WITH COEFFICIENTS

THE P3 INFECTION TIME IS W[1]-HARD PARAMETERIZED BY THE TREEWIDTH
=
THE P3 INFECTION TIME IS W-HARD PARAMETERIZED BY THE TREEWIDTH

DECYCLING WITH A MATCHING
=
DECYCLING WITH A MATCHING.

etc.
```

I imagine there is no such simple solution using distinct(), and I was not able to find any alternative commands to do that. So, if it is not possible and you can suggest any disambiguation algorithm I might use, I appreciate as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use a fuzzy match like `agrep` to collapse the minor variants first?

Comment: Are you sure that there are not 8 articles for the second journal?

Comment: Correct, Edward. I have miscounted the number of articles for the second journal. The correct would be 8, considering the similarities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `agrep` with `lapply` to find the *indices* of journal articles that are ≤10% dissimilar (the default for `agrep`, which you can change with the `max.distance` argument), then take the first article of each and vectorize it using `sapply`, get the `unique` indices, the length of the vector, and wrap a `tapply` around it all to select the number of "dissimilar" articles within each journal.

```
  tapply(data$PAPER, data$JOURNAL, FUN=function(x) {
      length(unique(sapply(lapply(x, function(y) agrep(y, x) ), "[", 1))
     } )

# 0001-1231 0001-1232 
#         6         8
```

For a dplyr version, which returns the results in a nicer format, I put the above code in a function, then used `group_by()` followed by `summarise()`.

```
dissimilar <- function(x, distance=0.1) {
  length(unique(sapply(lapply(x, function(y) 
     agrep(y, x, max.distance = distance) ), "[", 1)))
}
```

With "dissimilar" being defined according to the documentation of `agrep`.

```
library(dplyr)

data2 %>%
  group_by(JOURNAL) %>%
  summarise(n=dissimilar(PAPER))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  JOURNAL       n
  <chr>     <int>
1 0001-1231     6
2 0001-1232     8
```

However, for a larger dataset, such as one containing thousands of journals and 450,000+ articles, the above will be rather slow (about 10-15 minutes on my 2.50GHz Intel). I realised that the `dissimilar` function was unnecessarily comparing every row with every other row, which makes little sense. Ideally, each row should only be compared with itself and all *remaining rows*. For example, the first journal contains 5 very similar articles in rows 8-12. One use of `agrep` at row #8 returns all 5 indices, and therefore there is no need to compare rows 9-12 with any others. So I replaced the `lapply` with a for loop, and the process now takes only 2-3 minutes with a dataset of 450,000 rows.

```
dissimilar <- function(x, distance=0.1) {
  lst <- list()               # initialise the list
  k <- 1:length(x)            # k is the index of PAPERS to compare with
  for(i in k){                # i = each PAPER, k = itself and all remaining
    lst[[i]] <- agrep(x[i], x[k], max.distance = distance) + i - 1 
                              # + i - 1 ensures that the original index in x is maintained
    k <- k[!k %in% lst[[i]]]  # remove elements which are similar
  }
  lst <- sapply(lst, "[", 1)  # take only the first of each item in the list
  length(na.omit(lst))        # count number of elements
}
```

Now expand the original example dataset so that there are 450,000 records containing around 18,000 journals, each of which contain around 25 articles.

```
n <- 45000
data2 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(round(n/26), data, simplify=FALSE))[1:n,]
data2$JOURNAL[27:n] <- rep(paste0("0002-", seq(1, n/25)), each=25)[1:(n-26)]

data2 %>%
  group_by(JOURNAL) %>%
  summarise(n=dissimilar(PAPER))

# A tibble: 18,001 x 2
   JOURNAL        n
   <chr>      <int>
 1 0001-1231      6 # <-- Same
 2 0001-1232      8
 3 0002-1        14
 4 0002-10       14
 5 0002-100      14
 6 0002-1000     13
 7 0002-10000    14
 8 0002-10001    14
 9 0002-10002    14
10 0002-10003    14

# ... with 17,991 more rows
```

The challenge is to find a way to speed up the process even more.

Comment: Dear @Edward, this seems to be a great solution, but it seems to be very demanding in terms of processing (I've been running the script for around half an hour and it is still going). Is there a way to limit the function to run within groups? For example, I can group by journal and by publication year, and the script would compare titles only amongst the papers within these groups). Thanks again.

Comment: Yes - I should have tested that code on a much larger data set. In fact, we can limit the number of `agrep` comparisons substantially by only looking within each journal using `tapply`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Youre going to want to use a package that is meant for Natural Language Processing. Try the package quanteda.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but I don't think it might work in this case, as the list includes publication in several languages. A NLP would be great for English only content, but for this comparison, I need something that would compare combinations of characters, trying to find similarities without making sense of the contents. Thanks.

Comment: The LexNLP package has some multi-language support as well (but is python only). For arbitrary character clusters, you'll want to look into word-to-vec